# Eyes keep going outside of head

Tags: rigging

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I can't. The bones are parented correctly, the weight paint is correct. So why does this keep happening!?

Everytime I move the head , the eyes start going outside of it. I don't know why.

[image]

I can't fix this, I've tried everything and by all reason and logic this should work! I've done this dozens of times already and never encountered this. What the fluff is going on?

Can anyone look into this? I ran out of any kind of ideas.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: this one was hard to find  :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your head bone is segmented, bring the segmentation back to 1, otherwise it will deform the head shape, and it will look like the eyes go out:

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable. Simply unbelievable. I must've clicked there by accident when I was playing around with bendy bones for the neck and completely forgot.

Thank you for the help, once again.